# Particle filter for state space parameter estimation

Tags: filter, parameters, particles, estimation, state-space

Hello friends,
I have a doubtaboutn Particle filter for parameter estimation using state space model. I am able not to get inside the equations. I have attached the pictures of all equations.

1. Model of trend [This is for trend model for which I have to get the coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ribLm.png).
2. Initial parameter estimated. [Using Least Square Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xibXi.png).
3. Now, to find the model coefficients, these trend model is change to state space equations as attached image [Detail for each variable is given in next image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcI2n.png), [details for variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq4Bk.png)
4. Now they are changed to this. [Conversions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsn24.png)
5. Thats it. So, help me to get an understanding for solving these equations for parameter estimation.

I tried to understand these equations but unable to get those.